# nodejs to mysql connection error

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm getting error :
error:Error: Handshake inactivity timeout

Comment: Can you post the NodeJS code in context?

Comment: see this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20210522/nodejs-mysql-error-connection-lost-the-server-closed-the-connection

Comment: change `host : "127.0.0.1"` to `host : "localhost"`

Comment: @Subburaj I had tried that..but I want to connect without setTimeout i.e.I dont want to wake it up by setting timeout

Comment: @Abhik Chakraborty ..It dosn't works..Im receiving the same error.

Comment: @Gayathri post your code in question part not as a comment ... which helps all to find solution

Comment: @Gayathri, as what rev_dihazum said, please edit your question and put your code there instead of here.

Comment: @LFlare sorry  Im new to Stackoverflow

Comment: @Subburaj yes..still I'm struggling with this :(

Comment: @Gayathri can you post all the versions?like node,mysql,etc.

Comment: @Subburaj finnaly I found my error...error is in my XAMPP installation

Comment: Good that your problem solved..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [node-mysql](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql), It very easy to use. I have used once, Here is the example :-

```
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'me',
  password : 'secret',
  database : 'my_db'
});

connection.connect();

connection.query('SELECT 1 + 1 AS solution', function(err, rows, fields) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('The solution is: ', rows[0].solution);
});

connection.end();
```

Comment: I had installed node-mysql module.

Comment: Im using that only.Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

I connected mysql to node by like this.

Install mysql

npm install mysql

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

let connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    port: '8888',  /* port on which phpmyadmin run */
    password: 'root',
    database: 'dbname',
    socketPath: '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock' //for mac and linux
});

connection.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) {
      return console.error('error: ' + err.message);
    }

    console.log('Connected to the MySQL server.');
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Connection Pool:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var pool  = mysql.createPool({
  host     : 'example.org',
  user     : 'bob',
  password : 'secret'
});

pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
  // Use the connection
  connection.query( 'SELECT something FROM sometable', function(err, rows) {
    // And done with the connection.
    connection.release();

    // Don't use the connection here, it has been returned to the pool.
  });
});
```

Comment: But I dont know why Im getting this Error: Handshake inactivity timeout

Comment: This is related to node.js. refer this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33101869/solving-node-mysql-initialization-errors

Comment: I'm getting the same error after upgrading to node version 4.2.1 :(